# Estimating jump diffusion parameters from first passage time data?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, diffusion, langevin-diffusion

I know that there is a literature on approximating the first passage time distribution of jump diffusion processes. I know there is also a literature on estimating parameters of jump diffusion processes based off of observed data.

Is there a literature on estimating parameters of jump diffusion processes where the only data is first passage time data?

If so, could anyone point me in the direction of that literature?